# F# - Do ref cells need to be deleted explicitly?

Tags: pointers, f#, heap-memory, delete-operator, ref

Are ref cells like pointers in the sense that they reference data on the heap, and need to be explicitly deleted? All the examples I've seen online don't have explicit delete calls.

Comment: CLR is a garbage collected environment. You don't need to "delete" anything.

Comment: ... but sometimes you like to Dispose resources like files and connection. But that is not the case for ref cell that is a pure memory resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are ref cells like pointers in the sense that they reference data on the heap, and need to be explicitly deleted?

No.  F# runs on the CLR, which manages memory automatically via a garbage collector.  Memory resources, even ones that use the heap, do not need explicit cleanup from the developer, and in fact, there is no mechanism by which you can explicitly delete a specific object.

Instead, the reference cell will become eligible for garbage collection when there are no more references to it.  Sometime after that, it will get cleaned up automatically by the GC.

This is true for most types you generate in F#, as well, such as records, discriminated unions, classes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

How would you delete them explicitly?

Also if you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/1722f2ecd3fd6e4660cd27d52ac9b180e5c51851/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3413-L3424) you'll see that ref cell type is just an immutable wrapper over a mutable field, and the `:=` and `!` operators are [simply getter/setter calls](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/1722f2ecd3fd6e4660cd27d52ac9b180e5c51851/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3879-L3881).

You can implement ref in a similar way yourself quite easily:

```
type Ref<'a> = { mutable value: 'a }
let (:=) (r: Ref<_>) v = r.value <- v
let (!) (r: Ref<_>) = r.value
```